# Tests stuck on Configuring TestNG with: TestNG652Configurator

Tags: maven, junit, testng

I have some `TestNG` tests in my project running alongside of `jUnit` tests. Everyone coexists peacefully and stuff runs as expected, until one day instead of working all the time things changed to working some of the time.

When running `mvn clean install` tests get to the point of

```
Configuring TestNG with: TestNG652Configurator
```

and gets stuck. Nothing seems to happen since.

When running `mvn -X clean install` tests get to the exact same point without issues (no errors on top) and refuses to move further.

I am using

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
        <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
        <version>6.8</version>
    </dependency>
```

and

```
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.10</version>
    </dependency>
```

What can be going on here please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've never seen Surefire (the plugin that runs the tests) run tests from both JUnit and TestNG out-of-the-box, although it's supposed to do it.

You can force surefire to run both JUnit and TestNG by forcing the providers as explained [here](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/providers.html). For example, the following will force TestNG and JUnit 4.7

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.13</version>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.surefire</groupId>
      <artifactId>surefire-junit47</artifactId>
      <version>2.13</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.surefire</groupId>
      <artifactId>surefire-testng</artifactId>
      <version>2.13</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</plugin>
```

Another thing that might influence the result is if you have configured TestNG to run some test groups
.

Comment: With this as part of my pom, tests ran and showed the one which was hanging. This allowed me to investigate why this is happening and fix the issue. Without this snippet, tests showed no output. Thank you Augusto!

Comment: I used more verbose output for debugging - one can set in plugin conf: 

```<property>
 <name>surefire.testng.verbose</name>
 <value>10</value>
</property>```